# Bring real data tables with FK

Tags: ajax, database, django, json

I have 3 classes: Document, Layout and Company

1 Document has 1 Layout and 1 Company.

```
Document class:
    layout = models.ForeignKey (Layout)
    company = models.ForeignKey (Company)
```

I have a search page that is being filled by JSON, then the data layout and the company is returning the ID of them respectively, and the ideal would be to show the names of each data (Name and Company Name Layout).

How can I accomplish this query as quoted above?

Comment: [So, what have you tried!?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a `__unicode__(self):` method for `Layout` and `Company`.

It might look something like:

```
class Layout(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Of course, I'm only guessing at what your `Layout` class looks like. You'll have to change `__unicode__` to make it appropriate for your model.

In the future, try to search the Django Documentation. It's actually quite good. Here's the relevant information for what you're asking. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#unicode

Comment: Daniel, i found how to this:
Using natural_keys 

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/#natural-keys

Thanks